# jquery getjson cross domain issue

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get some html code from another page and insert it into a page that is on another website.
So the issue is getting a cross domain $.get() call to work. 
But most people recommend using json to solve the issue.

This is the php file I use

```
<?php
$arr = array(array("test","this is a string"));
$arr['name'] = "response";
echo $_GET['callback'] . "('" . json_encode($arr) . "')";
?>
```

This is the function I use, it uses jquery

```
function getJson(site, callback){
    $.ajax({
         url:site,
         dataType: 'JSONP',
         success:function(json){
            callback(json);
         },
         error:function(){
            //handle error
         },
    });
}
```

This is how I access it

```
getJson("http://websitename.com/page.php?callback=?", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

alert displays this string

```
('{"0":["test","this is a string"],"name":"response"}')
```

My question is, how can I access the data variable as if it were json

```
data.test;
data["test"];
```

edit: solved my own question again

I used

```
$.parseJSON(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot - unless it allows it explicit.
Use http header on the server side:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

I don't know who told you to use json but they were wrong. Ajax (not json, json is something else) can not cross domains. and you can not read the HTML from say an iFrame if the domain is different.

You can use a server side proxy to do this for you if you must, but remember the request will be in the context of the server, not the client.

Edit:

I just realized you are doing jsonp! (I thought you were trying to get html.)

All you need to do is add:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

to the request and it should work.

Comment: Ajax can, in fact, [cross domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Comment: @malvolio since it's not supported by all browsers, to me, it doesn't count.

Comment: *Javascript* isn't supported by all browsers.  At some point, you have to let go of obsolete versions of bad browsers.

Comment: @malvolio yah but IE7? You still need to support that, and it doesn't even work all that well in IE8. It doesn't work in Opera, and it doesn't work in Firefox before 3.5. So it's too early.

Comment: @malvolio And can you reverse the downmod (if it was you)? Because I think my answer is fine.

Comment: I've been been using CORS in consumer-facing websites for two years, never had a user complain.  Old versions of IE are the province of people stuck in huge corporations with dictatorial and hide-bound IT departments.  Those people are beyond saving; we have to save the rest.  Put a disclaimer at the top of your answer, something like "Since CORS only works on browsers released after 2007, anyone writing sites that need to work on geriatric platform should be aware..." and I'll grudgingly un-down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use JSONP, which *will not work*.  JSONP works when you are retrieving specially-formatted JSON data.  The data you are trying to get is HTML, not JSON, as Ariel points out, and wouldn't be properly formatted.  Jacek's suggestion is the correct one if you have control over the remote server; otherwise, yes, you'll need a server-side proxy (on the local server) as Ariel says.

**EDIT:** if you get to change the question, I get to change the answer.

The only thing I can see you're doing wrong is the *you* are specifying `callback` in the URL --  jQuery will take care of this for you -- and that you are writing JSONP in upper-case.  I can't believe either of these is actually the problem.  If the Firebug net tab is not showing the request being made, step through the jQuery code (it isn't that complicated) and see why not.

Comment: I'm now actually unsure if he's trying to get HTML. I think he may be trying to get jsonp to work.

Comment: I am getting json data with html in one of the variables. It should still work and return it as plain text.

Comment: I have solved the original problem of getting the json data across a domain as specified in my question. The issue that remains is formatting it from a plain text string into json format of accessing it with brackets or by name.

Comment: Post your solution and file a new question.

Comment: I have already posted the solution to the issue, and edited in my current question

Comment: Problem *could* be the upper-case JSONP; it *could* be that your server is not setting the MIME-type correctly; it could be something else.  Step through the jQuery code and find out.  Or you can cut the Gordian knot and call `$.parseJSON` ...